Sum of odd reciprocals
Can (n-1)/n be expressed as sum of random "odd" distinct reciprocals ever? here 'n' is also an odd.

Nice question. It seems to have been asked before, in only a slightly different form: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276725/can-the-sum-of-finitely-many-inverses-of-distinct-odd-integers-geq-3-be-1 where 1 is expressed as a sum of distinct odd reciprocals.

For a concrete example, $1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/9 + 1/11 + 1/15 + 1/35 + 1/45 = 230/231$.
